# How to avoid ambiguity and convey specific meaning in compound names ? (name + name)

Tags: compounds, compound-words

There are already other questions regarding compound names (noun + noun) and now I better understand the general rule, which seems to be, unless dealing with an exception, to only make plural one of the names, usually the last. I encounter is how to be  more specific  and convey the actual  meaning, particularly in cases where there are no preceding articles or objectives.
for example the sentence

> please find figure descriptions in section 4

This should be the correct form. But how to convey different meanings:
1. There could be many descriptions for one figure
2. There could be many descriptions for each of many figures
3. There could be one description for each of many figures

So the example above  can be misleading or ambiguous. I am interested in the formal use in books or scientific articles. Again, this might have been in telegraphic sentences where the number of words as to be kept to a minimum.

Comment: You're asking about *not avoiding* ambiguity, i.e. you *want* it to be ambiguous. I'm guessing that the *noun + noun* construct you're interested in is "figure descriptions". That already includes the ambiguity you're seeking, and it covers all the three cases you listed.

Comment: @Lawrence I changed  the question title and forgot to delete the 'not',  was not clear from my  question that I wanted to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: No, it wasn't. Your "*how to convey different meanings*" can be read to say you want a single expression that ambiguously conveys the listed meanings, or to say that you want separate expressions that unambiguously convey each listed meaning. The title helps to determine which reading to choose. Since it asked at the time "how not to avoid ambiguity", the rest of the question was read with that in mind.

Comment: In your example it seems not to matter at all.

Singular, plural or hypothetical what circumstance is not covered by *please find figure descriptions in section 4*, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin to me cases 2 and 3 that I have listed seem ambiguous, aren't they?

Comment: They are not, in English. How that translates to arithmetic is a different question. Still what d’you think isn’t covered by find figure descriptions in section 4? What rule says unless dealing with an exception, make plural only one name, usually the last? 

Cases 2 and 3 are ambiguous, in arithmetic, as is case 1. What to make plural depends on context, not word order. If you want to play with theoretical logic you might have a point; not in English. Why would you limit your thoughts to those you chose? Figure description; figure descriptions; figures description; figures descriptions?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I read that general rule I think somewhere on SE, or some credible grammar website. And from the majority of the text I have read that seems to be the rule. I don't care about it being theoretical, and of course should be logical, but not all grammar rules are necessarily logical.

Comment: Are you using *make plural only one name* for Secretaries of State or Attorney Generals? If so where does any *exception* fit?
I now think the Question isn’t about ambiguity, but suitability; broadly, whether to use *all* or *each*. Kick me, who saw that before.
*… figure descriptions…* includes *many descriptions for one figure* and *many descriptions for each of many*; not *one description for each of many*.
Are you seeking *… figure description…* or *… figure’s description…*, i.e. *one description for one figure* and neither *many for many…* nor *one for many* or *one for each of many*?